# landscape longtblr with tabularray and multi page in standalone environment

Tags: tables, longtable, standalone, landscape, tabularray

I'm using the `longtblr` environment of the relatively new package `tabularray` to typeset a very long table that spans several pages, and I'm also using the `standalone` package to alter it in a isolated environment.

I'm facing multiple problems that I don't know how to solve, and this is why I'm asking for your help.

First of all, the `multi` option of the `standalone` package causes the page margins to be messed up, hence I am unable to divide the table into numerous pages without compromising the margins.

Second, I want to keep editing the table in a horizontal layout and rotate it only in the main document (which uses the `book` class), but I'm not sure if it would work with an external import like `\includestandalone{path/to/my/table}`.

---

```
\documentclass[
    varwidth=24.7cm,% 29.7 - 2.5 * 2
    % multi,
]{standalone}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtblr}[
    caption={Caption.},
]{
    colspec = {
        X[2,l]
        X[1.5,l]
        X[1.8,l]
        X[2,l]
        S[table-format=7]
        S[table-format=6]
        S[table-format=6]
    },
    % COLUMNS
    column{1-9} = {font=\footnotesize},
    % COLUMN SEPARATOR
    colsep = {5pt},
    % ROWS
    rowhead = 1,
    % FIRST ROW
    row{1} = {guard, font=\footnotesize\bfseries, bg=lightgray},
    % HORIZONTAL LINES
    hline{3-Y} = {.5pt, lightgray},
  }
    \toprule
        Title & Name and entity & Leader & Partner & {Total\\amount} & {Lorem\\amount} & {Ipsum\\amount}\\*
    \midrule
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & consectetur adipiscing elit & Lorem ipsum & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit & 16000 & 4000 & 6000\\*
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & consectetur adipiscing elit & Lorem ipsum & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit & 16000 & 4000 & 6000\\*
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & consectetur adipiscing elit & Lorem ipsum & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit & 16000 & 4000 & 6000\\*
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & consectetur adipiscing elit & Lorem ipsum & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit & 16000 & 4000 & 6000\\*
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & consectetur adipiscing elit & Lorem ipsum & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit & 16000 & 4000 & 6000\\*
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & consectetur adipiscing elit & Lorem ipsum & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit & 16000 & 4000 & 6000\\*
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & consectetur adipiscing elit & Lorem ipsum & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit & 16000 & 4000 & 6000\\*
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & consectetur adipiscing elit & Lorem ipsum & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit & 16000 & 4000 & 6000\\*
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & consectetur adipiscing elit & Lorem ipsum & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit & 16000 & 4000 & 6000\\\pagebreak
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & consectetur adipiscing elit & Lorem ipsum & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit & 16000 & 4000 & 6000\\*
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & consectetur adipiscing elit & Lorem ipsum & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit & 16000 & 4000 & 6000\\*
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & consectetur adipiscing elit & Lorem ipsum & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit & 16000 & 4000 & 6000\\*
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & consectetur adipiscing elit & Lorem ipsum & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit & 16000 & 4000 & 6000\\*
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & consectetur adipiscing elit & Lorem ipsum & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit & 16000 & 4000 & 6000\\*
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & consectetur adipiscing elit & Lorem ipsum & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit & 16000 & 4000 & 6000\\*
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & consectetur adipiscing elit & Lorem ipsum & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit & 16000 & 4000 & 6000\\*
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & consectetur adipiscing elit & Lorem ipsum & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit & 16000 & 4000 & 6000\\*
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & consectetur adipiscing elit & Lorem ipsum & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit & 16000 & 4000 & 6000\\\pagebreak
    \bottomrule
  \end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't use the `standalone` class. Use whatever class you're using in the main document, with appropriate settings in the preamble. Keep the `standalone` package in your main file. Then you can work on it separately, but `\input` it without having to delete the preamble. `standalone` will ensure the preamble is skipped. It doesn't care what class it is - it's going to skip it anyway. [But if you have anything *before* `\documentclass`, you need to handle it specially. Also avoid TeX `\if ... \fi`s in the preamble as `standalone` chokes on them.]